# Javadoc tooltip hides when I click on it

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, gtk, gtk3, ubuntu-18.04

I recently upgraded **Ubuntu** to **18.04** and starting using **Eclipse Photon** (Fresh package).

When I hover over a class or a method to view it's Javadoc, and then click on the tooltip, the tooltip disappears. This didn't happen before and I've been using Eclipse and Ubuntu for many years.

This also happens while inspecing a variable. I expect the tooltips to stay visible as they used to before.

I attached 2 screencasts to demonstrate.

**Clicking a javadoc tooltip**
[image]

**Clicking a variable inspection tooltip**
[image]

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue with the [latest integration build](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/)? If yes, please report it to Eclipse. Would `SWT_GTK3=0` be a workaround for you?

Comment: I did so by running `export SWT_GTK3=0` before starting Eclipse and it fixed the problem but it ruined the look and feel. Is there a way to keep the look and feel and fix the problem too ? I'm using `June 2018` build.

Comment: I see, so it is definitely a GTK 3.x issue. Can you reproduce this issue with the [Eclipse SDK I20180827-2000](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/I20180827-2000/)? If no, the bug has already been fixed and you can switch to a milestone release of the upcoming release 2018-09. If yes, it might be [Eclipse bug 486316](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=486316) on which you should comment on: what happens when you do `export SWT_WEBKIT2=1`?, was anything logged in the _Error Log_ view?, etc.

Comment: @howlger, done. https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=486316#c31

Answer (score 2):

Settings > Keyboard > [Input source switching] Choose "Use the same source for all windows"

[image: Use the same source for all windows]

Comment: The bug is still presented in Eclipse 2023-12 running in Ubuntu 20. Changing the above settings will help.